# Python web scraping, symbols meaning

Tags: python, web-scraping

In below code, what does each and every element of the symbol string `re.sub('<[^>]*>|[\n]|\[[0-9]*\]', '', htmlread)` mean?

```
import urllib2
import re

htmltext = urllib2.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkin_Park")
htmlread = htmltext.read()
htmlread = re.sub('<[^>]*>|[\n]|\[[0-9]*\]', '', htmlread)
regex = '(?<=Linkin Park was founded)(.*)(?=the following year.)'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
htmlread = re.findall(pattern, htmlread)
print "Linkin Park was founded" + htmlread[0] + "the following year."
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 0):

The line `htmlread = re.sub('<[^>]*>|[\n]|\[[0-9]*\]', '', htmlread)` removes either

- an expression between `<>` OR
- a newline
- a number between brackets or empty brackets

from htmlread

interesting wiki post here: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Replace every character with '', that means delete it from htmlread variable

Please read more about RegEx